# Galois group of a splitting field

Tags: galois-theory

Let G be the Galois group of the splitting field of $(x^p)-2$ over Q, where p is odd prime , Then which of the following are correct? 
(1)  G has an element of order 4 if $p=5$.
(2)  G has an element of order $p-1$.
(3)  G is non abelian.
(4)  G is abelian for some $p$.

Comment: There are no finite fields in this question.

Comment: It's a good idea to start with examples.  You can read about $x^3-2$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/galois-group-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q).

Comment: $x^p-2$ or $x^{p-2}$ ?

Comment: $x^{p-2}$ is trivial, @Isham

Comment: I edit it so please see it again.

Comment: Calling this [a duplicate of this older one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/463671/11619). This question also looks like a copy/pasted homework problem. Suggesting closure.

Comment: I agree that this question may be similar to a problem that is discussed previously but this is a different one.

Comment: If it is duplicate then what are correct options of above question? Please help.