# Determine the Galois group of a reducible quartic polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The polynomial is $x^4-2x^3-2x+4$ which is reducible over $\mathbb Q$ as it has a root $x=2$. The cubic resolvent for this polynominal is $x^3-16x-20$. It is irreducible and its determinant equals $2^4\cdot 349$, meaning that the Galois group for the resolvent is $S_3$. I found information on how to determine the Galois group for irreducible quartic polynomials based on the information about its cubic resolvent, but nothing about the case when it's reducible.

Comment: That's a quartic, not a quadratic.  After factoring, it is $(x-2)(x^3-2)$ so you really only care about $x^3-2$, which is a [standard example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/galois-group-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q)

Comment: @lulu Thank you. I am sorry, English is not my first language. So will the Galois group of $x^3-2$ be equal to the one of quartic polynominal?

Comment: Yes, as they have the same splitting field.